# Kendo mvc upload required validation

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I'm trying to validate kendo uploads but I can't handle with that.

```
<form method="post" id="projectRequestForm">
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("specFiles")
        .Validation(v => v.MaxFileSize(10485760))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { required = "required" })
    )
</form>
```

problem is that "required" is not working. I can check in c# method if upload is empty or not, but I need to validate this from jquery side. All the other fields in form are validating well,

Comment: can you try required = true instead?

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma I did, it's hitting my OnPost method also

Comment: what is the generated html in the browser? required field will only work in html5 control

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma it's weird, because if I click "select files" and don't pick any error message appears, but it doesn't work when I click submit button

Comment: ahh.. looks like you will have to use separate script on submit click to validate this.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma and how can I combine them somehow to have 1 complex validation based on few scripts?

Comment: you will have to share the rendered html code so it can easily be understood and we can provide better help.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma can you paste some example on jsfiddle?